# How to Loop a List and Extract required data (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python

I need help in looping a list and extracting the `src` links. This is my list and the code:

```
getimages = getDetails.find_all('img')
#deleting the first image in the list
getimages[0].decompose()
print(getimages)
```

The output of getimages list is :

```
[<None></None>]
[<None></None>, <img border="0" data-original-height="855" data-original-width="1885" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mq2ilVOcyPQ/X70khVD9UaI/AAAAAAAArLw/xC2LggPdcRUTm3aTGpPFYhoM6rDJwbyzACLcBGAsYHQ/s16000-rw/ssc-admit-card.webp"/>]
[<None></None>]
```

This is how I am looping to extract the `src` image :

```
try:
  for x in getimages:
      print (x['src'])
except :
    print("Image not found")
```

The output is always `Image Not found` , but the image is present in the list, How can i fix it, please guide. Thanks

Comment: Why do you use the try-except? You're hiding the actual problem! (And a bare except is a really bad practice, which you should almost never use).

Answer (score -1):

## Solution: use regEx

```
import re
regular_expression = r'<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>'
for ia in getimages:
    list_link = list(re.findall(regular_expression, ia))
    print(list_link[-1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).