# Python : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I have this list :

```
>>print(new_list)

[<None></None>]
[<None></None>, <img border="0" data-original-height="855" data-original-width="1885" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mq2ilVOcyPQ/X70khVD9UaI/AAAAAAAArLw/xC2LggPdcRUTm3aTGpPFYhoM6rDJwbyzACLcBGAsYHQ/s16000-rw/ssc-admit-card.webp"/>]
[<None></None>]
```

When I try to loop :

```
 for p in new_list:
    print(p['src'])
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I loop and get the items without the error?

Comment: You need to review how you're populating *new_list*

Comment: You've asked pretty much the same question 2 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938706/ the difference being that now you do not discard the exception by wrapping your code in a try..except

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Loop a List and Extract required data (Beautiful Soup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938706/how-to-loop-a-list-and-extract-required-data-beautiful-soup)

Comment: no, i am getting the items, but needed to extract the only src part, and not the whole item

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to print the `None`s, and only print the elements with a `'src'` attribute.

```
for p in new_list:
    if p and p['src']:
        print(p['src'])
```